# Bootstrap 4 accordions not opening on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have a page with Boostrap 4 accordions.

When in responsive mode in Chrome, they do open. But, trying on an actual Android phone or iPhone, they don't open. I'm baffled. Any ideas? (I've added JS and jQuery as tags as I'm pretty sure that could be the issue, sorry if it's not.)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



   <!-- MOBILE VERSION -->  
 <div class="d-md-none">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
        <div class="card mb-0">
            <div class="card-header text-center collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                <a class="card-title">
                    Mon - 00/00/00
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
                <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                    aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
                    craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-header text-center collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                <a class="card-title">
                    Tues - 00/00/00
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
                <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                    aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
                    craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-header text-center collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
                <a class="card-title">
                    Wed - 00/00/00
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
                <div class="card-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                    aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. samus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-header text-center collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">
                <a class="card-title">
                    Wed - 00/00/00
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSeven" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
                <div class="card-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                    aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. samus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>                                                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: @lonut, that's odd. It doesn't could you check here too please: http://test-checker.com/booking-test.html, that'll confirm that it's maybe the order of my resources or something..

Comment: I've tested this page and it works on my android phone. You just have to click on the link not in the block, otherwise, it could be an cache issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to add the CSS cursor:pointer to the accordion div.